# SQL Replication components install in 2016 standard edition

Tags: replication, sql-server-2016

i would like to install the components of Replication in sql server where the initial installation version is 2016 standard with SP1 (KB 3182545) - 13.1.4001.0 but now the SQL version is 2016 standard (SP1-CU7-GDR) (KB4057119) - 13.0.4466.4.

Question: Will this be good to go ahead and install components with initial setup file ?

Answer (score 2):

Your currently installed instance is at version 13.0.4466.4 (2016 SP1-CU7-GDR), and your installation media is at a lower patch level for the same major version (in your case, 2016 SP1, without the CU).

When you install an additional component (Replication, Full-text search, etc) with install media at a lower version, the installation will succeed, but those components will be unpatched. Essentially, the database engine & previously installed bits will be at one version (SP1-CU7) and the newly installed bits will be at a lower version.

After installing the additional components, you will want to re-patch the instance to install the CU. This will ensure that all components on the instance are at a consistent patch level, and ensure you have a supported configuration.

Essentially, whether you're installing additional components or a brand new instance, you'll want to run through the same combination of installers to ensure you get the desired major version + SP + CU.